# Return Value from SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, tableadapter

I have a stored procedure in a Microsoft SQL Server database:

```
USE [ProjectIndexer]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [files].[add_file]    Script Date: 12/12/2014 1:34:20 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [files].[add_file]
    @FILENAME varchar(255),
    @EXTENSION nvarchar(8),
    @PATH_FULL varchar(255), 
    @RELATIVE_PATH varchar(255), 
    @JOB varchar(15), 
    @DATE_MODIFIED datetimeoffset(7), 
    @SIZE BIGINT, 
    @INDEX_MODULE INT, 
    @FILE_TYPE varchar(255), 
    @DOC_TYPE varchar(255), 
    @DISCIPLINE varchar(255)
AS
    DECLARE @file_id sql_variant

    --Insert values for new file 
    INSERT INTO files.GENERAL 
        (FILENAME, EXTENSION, PATH_FULL, RELATIVE_PATH, JOB, DATE_MODIFIED, SIZE, INDEX_MODULE, FILE_TYPE, DOC_TYPE, DISCIPLINE) 
        VALUES(@FILENAME, @EXTENSION, @PATH_FULL, @RELATIVE_PATH, @JOB, @DATE_MODIFIED, @SIZE, @INDEX_MODULE, @FILE_TYPE, @DOC_TYPE, @DISCIPLINE);

    --Get the ID of this new file
    SELECT @file_id = current_value FROM sys.sequences WHERE name = 'FILE_ID_SEQ';

--Return ID
RETURN CONVERT(bigint, @file_id)
```

I am trying to run this procedure in a VB application developed in Visual Studio 2012, using table adapters:

```
Dim myFilesGeneralTableAdapter As New FILES_GeneralTableAdapter
Dim FileID As Int32

FileID = myFilesGeneralTableAdapter.AddFile(FileName, fileExtension, foundFile, fileRelativePath, JobNumber, fileDateModified, fileSize, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
```

For some reason, the function isn't returning the value to the VB variable 'FileID'. I can, however, use the "Preview Data" feature in the dataset designer to insert values for the above parameters in Visual Studio, and in that environment I'm able to get a returned value.

This suggests to me that my syntax in my VB module is wrong.  Can anyone tell me what the error is?

Comment: The problem may be in your FILES_GeneralTableAdapter object. Can you post the code for that?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: `TableAdapter` is a pretty old technology. You'd probably find it easier to get help if you used something more modern, like Entity Framework.

Comment: A side note, your fileId is int32, but you are returning a big int (int64) from the procedure.

Comment: I don't think I have any code for that.  I created it in the "Data Sources" window of Visual Studio.  I can see it visually in the dataset designer and it has the stored procedure in there.  How can I post code for the table adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand? You can use it to call your stored procedure, add the parameter values, and execute it in such a way that you retrieve a single value, i.e.

```
Try
    'Create command'
    Dim command As New SqlCommand
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    conn = New SqlConnection(myConnString)
    command.Connection = conn
    command.CommandText = "add_file"

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Filename", [Filename])
    ...
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Discipline", Discipline)

    command.Connection.Open()
    Dim i As Int64 = command.ExecuteScalar()
    command.Connection.Close()

    'returns record ID'
    Return i

Catch ex As Exception
    Throw ex
Finally
    If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then
        conn.Close()
    End If
End Try
```

Please note that, in this example, "myConnString" is a String with the value of my connection string for the database I'm connecting to.

Answer (score 0):

I took the good advice of transitioning the script to an Entity Framework model.  At first, the stored procedure did not return what I wanted (it only returned an integer value of 1), but I found a resource online that instructed me to create a "Function Import" in the EF model.  After doing that and properly matching variable types I managed to get the stored procedure to return the right value in Visual Studio.  Here's a good resoure:

http://www.devtoolshed.com/using-stored-procedures-entity-framework-scalar-return-values

Answer (score 0):

Outside of converting from `TableAdapter` to Entity Framework (a good move regardless), you would be much_better off returning such a value as either an `OUTPUT` parameter or in a result set. A stored procedure return value is really intended to convey a status code of the operation and is hence pretty limited.

Also, by doing the following operation after the `INSERT` (i.e. as a separate step),

```
--Get the ID of this new file
SELECT @file_id = current_value FROM sys.sequences WHERE name = 'FILE_ID_SEQ';
```

you are risking getting an incorrect value if some other process inserts into that table at roughly the same time (i.e. between this particular `INSERT` and this particular `SELECT`).

Given both of the above issues, it would be fairly simple, and very reliable, to instead use the [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause on the `INSERT` statement:

```sql
--Insert values for new file
INSERT INTO files.GENERAL
    (FILENAME, EXTENSION, PATH_FULL, RELATIVE_PATH, JOB, DATE_MODIFIED, SIZE,
     INDEX_MODULE, FILE_TYPE, DOC_TYPE, DISCIPLINE)
  OUTPUT INSERTED.FILE_ID
  VALUES(@FILENAME, @EXTENSION, @PATH_FULL, @RELATIVE_PATH, @JOB, @DATE_MODIFIED,
         @SIZE, @INDEX_MODULE, @FILE_TYPE, @DOC_TYPE, @DISCIPLINE);
```

That will generate a 1 row, 1 column result set. The column will be named `FILE_ID` or whatever the actual field name is (I guess based on the naming convention used for the other fields and the variable).

Then get rid of the `DECLARE @file_id`, the `SELECT ...`, and the `RETURN ...`.